# Possible to make bitlocker prompt for password everytime?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, bitlocker

I want a solution that will encrypt my drives and ask for password the first time I try to access a drive after boot, is BitLocker able to do that? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

In windows 8.1:

If you use bitlocker with password authentication it will ask you to unlock your drive the first time you access it every time you sign in. It will stay unlocked until you reboot.

Windows 7 and 8 should be similar/the same.